# What does the "i" stand for in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking at a bunch of SQL query's made by another individual and am trying to interpret how they were made.  I'm fairly new to SQL so its involved a lot of Googling, its also my first time posting a SQL question.

I've seen the letter "i" entered in a lot of queries. Below is an example query.  Does anyone know what this "i" stands for in the "select year (i.InspectDate)" line"?

```
-- Inspection Counts by Type

-- Facility inspections (and a few others) are not associated with wells -- therefore I removed the join to 
-- the Well table to get the correct counts


declare @year int
select @year = '2018'

select year(i.InspectDate), i.InspectType, rc.description, count(i.PKey) 
from Inspect I 
left join refcodes rc on rc.code = i.InspectType and rc.Fld = 'inspecttype'
where i.InspectType in ('AR', 'AI', 'BO', 'CO', 'CR', 'DO', 'DR', 'ER', 'ES', 'EMIT', 'RF', 'FR', 'MW', 'GE', 
'IMIT', 'MITNONWIT', 'CV', 'BT', 'PA', 'PO', 'RP', 'SEISMIC', 'SI', 'SR', 'UI', 'VI', 'WR')
and year(i.InspectDate) = @year
group by year(i.InspectDate), i.InspectType, rc.description
order by rc.description


select 'Totals', count(i.PKey) 
from Inspect I 
left join refcodes rc on rc.code = i.InspectType and rc.Fld = 'inspecttype'
where i.InspectType in ('AR', 'AI', 'BO', 'CO', 'CR', 'DO', 'DR', 'ER', 'ES', 'EMIT', 'RF', 'FR', 'MW', 'GE', 
'IMIT', 'MITNONWIT', 'CV', 'BT', 'PA', 'PO', 'RP', 'SEISMIC', 'SI', 'SR', 'UI', 'VI', 'WR')
and year(i.InspectDate) = @year 


-- select * from inspect


/*
InspectType RefCodes

X   AI  Audit
X   AR  Administrative Request
X   BT  OTHER
X   CO  Casing/Cement Operations
X   CR  Complaint
X   CV  Non-Compliance Verification
X   DR  Drilling
X   ER  Emergency Response
X   FR  Final Restoration/Bond Release
X   MW  MIT Witnessed   
X   PA  Plugging
X   PO  Presite
            0   PW  Plugging Witnessed  (NOT USED)
X   RP  Production/Environmental
X   WR  Workover/Recompletion
X   SI  Spill/Incident
X   RF  Facility Inspection
X   IMIT    Internal Mechanical Integrity Test
X   EMIT    External Mechanical Integrity Test
X   VI  Verification Inspection
X   UI  UIC Well
X   BO  BOPE
X   DO  Documentation
X   GE  Geophysical Exploration
X   ES  Environmental/Sampling
X   SR  Step Rate Test
X   SEISMIC Seismic Inspection
X   MITNONWIT   MIT Not Witnessed
            0   UNKNOWN Unknown (NOT USED)
*/
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What "i"? There's lots in the query? Do you mean the alias `I`?

Comment: `I` is a table alias.  It is defined in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Alias (just alternate name you can use so you do not need to use the full table name in your queries), but not a very descriptive one.

Comment: @Larnu e.g "select year(i.InspectDate)".  I'm referring to the "i" in this line (and others).

Comment: Aliases are nice.  Meaningless aliases, not so much. At least imho.

Comment: Aside: these two queries can be combined by using `GROUPING SETS` so `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (year(i.InspectDate), i.InspectType, rc.description), ( ) )` this gives you two separate groupings. Also, it will probably be more efficient if the `WHERE` was filtering on `i.InspectDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@year, 1, 1) AND i.InspectDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@year + 1, 1, 1)` instead of `YEAR(i.i.InspectDate)`, so that it can use an index. These may be above your level now, but bear them in mind for when you get to a more advanced level

Comment: @Charlieface Definitely above my head for now but I'll be learning.  Looks like I'll be in SQL most days at work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), declared here:

```
from Inspect I
```

Remember SQL is not case sensitive, so the `I` alias declared as a mnemonic for the `Inspect` table is the same `i` used in the `SELECT` list.

It's *good practice* to use table/view aliases in queries, because aside from saving you a bunch of typing you sometimes need to reference more than one instance of the same table; aliases allow you to disambiguate which instance you mean. They also help with query portability.

This question demonstrates the use of single-letter or very short mnemonics for each table/view. Single-letter variables are discouraged in most programming circles, but it's fine for this purpose, as long as it's a mnemonic for the full name. The practice is very common and well-understood among database developers. You may, however, sometimes run into *sequential* single-letter aliases (`a`, `b`, `c`, continuing in the order the tables/views appear), and that is  **not** good practice.

Comment: Ok.  Shouldn't it be written as, "from Inspect as I"?  Can you skip using the "AS" command?

Comment: Yes, the `As` keyword is optional

Comment: Gotcha.  I have a lot to learn it seems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the docs for the `FROM` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) :

> ```
> -- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  
>   
> [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
> <table_source> ::=   
> {  
>     table_or_view_name [ FOR SYSTEM_TIME <system_time> ] [ AS ] table_alias ]
> ```

> `[AS] table_alias` Is an alias for table_source that can be used either
> for convenience or to distinguish a table or view in a self-join or
> subquery. An alias is frequently a shortened table name used to refer
> to specific columns of the tables in a join. If the same column name
> exists in more than one table in the join, SQL Server requires that
> the column name be qualified by a table name, view name, or alias. The
> table name cannot be used if an alias is defined.

Here, you have

```
from Inspect I
```

This means that instead of typing `Inspect.` every time you want to refer to columns of that table, you can (and indeed must) just say `I.`.

It saves time writing and reading. Most experienced query-writers will use aliases that go some way to suggest which table is which. For example if you join `Orders` to `Products`, use `O` and `P`.

Comment: Ok. I think I'm getting closer to understanding what was done here... The "I" refers to the "Inspect" table data, right?  If so, does it matter that the "i" in,"select year.(i.InspectDate) is lower-case?  Its curious that the, "from Inspect I" uses upper-case and then the selection uses lower-case.

Comment: As Joel said, sql is case-insensitive, as should be apparent from the fact that the query works.